# Error Docker deployment in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - Docker container quit unexpectedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I am trying deploy a simple docker container through Elastic Beanstalk but I am getting Docker container quit unexpectedly error. Not sure what is wrong here. Thanks in advance for the help.

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "janedoe/image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [{
    "ContainerPort": "10010"
  }],
  "Volumes": [{
    "HostDirectory": "/home/ec2-user/testdocker",
    "ContainerDirectory": "/home/ec2-user/testdocker"
  }],
  "Logging": "/home/ec2-user/testlogs"
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos6
MAINTAINER janedoe
```

RUN echo "test"
EXPOSE 10010

Log :

```
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.034Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application       update/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Completed activity.     
Result:
  centos6: Pulling from library/centos
  Digest: sha256:ec1bf627545d77d05270b3bbd32a9acca713189c58bc118f21abd17ff2629e3f
  Status: Image is up to date for centos:centos6
  Successfully pulled centos:centos6
  Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
  Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB

  Step 1 : FROM centos:centos6
   ---> ed452988fb6e
  Step 2 : MAINTAINER janedoe
   ---> Running in 8bce7dfb7e59
   ---> 04de6fffed04
  Removing intermediate container 8bce7dfb7e59
  Step 3 : RUN echo "test"
   ---> Running in 36cef1d7c0e5
  test
   ---> c5b3d119184c
  Removing intermediate container 36cef1d7c0e5
  Step 4 : EXPOSE 10010
   ---> Running in ea07cbcc1136
   ---> 45f9b3fe6503
  Removing intermediate container ea07cbcc1136
  Successfully built 45f9b3fe6503
  Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.034Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.035Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.550Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.550Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.587Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2016-03-22T22:56:35.588Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-22T22:56:36.107Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from .
[2016-03-22T22:56:36.107Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 0 completed
[2016-03-22T22:56:36.107Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-22T22:56:36.108Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-22T22:56:36.108Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-22T22:56:44.157Z] INFO  [15895] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: 268f1a5e43874771bc6039977e9eb048e704c0b94a5e100a2a9ffbf2d9d7f271
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Tue Mar 22 22:56:44 UTC 2016:. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: 268f1a5e43874771bc6039977e9eb048e704c0b94a5e100a2a9ffbf2d9d7f271
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Tue Mar 22 22:56:44 UTC 2016:. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Comment: Did you check the logs of your applications (the one managed by AWS EB in S3)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a CMD instead of a RUN on your Dockerfile.

When executing commands in a Dockerfile, you must choose carefully between RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT (extracted from the [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)):

- RUN:

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of
>   the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed
>   image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

- CMD:

> The main purpose of a CMD is to **provide defaults for an executing
>   container**. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
>   the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT
>   instruction as well.

- ENTRYPOINT:

> An ENTRYPOINT allows you to configure a container that will run as an
>   executable.

You should have a deep read to the [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and to the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Apart from that, if you intend to use the volumes you defined in your Dockerrun.aws.json, have in mind what is stated in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html#create_deploy_docker_image_dockerfile%22documentation%22):

> Do not specify the Image key in the Dockerrun.aws.json file when using
>   a Dockerfile. .Elastic Beanstalk will always build and use the image
>   described in the Dockerfile when one is present.

This means that your Dockerrun.aws.json will be ignored, so take care.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to just see the command prompt output if your run it like

```
eb create <replace_with_your_env_name/> -vvv
```